# Set layout with listview selected item - Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, adapter

I have a problem.

- I want redirect layout with the selected item on the listview.
- And the layout I want to redirect has empty view objects and I want
  to fill them with data from the selected listview object
- But I can't, I did debug and I'm getting an error on line 67 with
  click the listview object. What should I do?

Please help me I have homework

This code in onCreate method
Code :

```
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lw_yemekTarifleri);
    customAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(this, yemekTarifleriList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Log.i("OnClick", "position = " + position);


            ImageView yemekResim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iw_yemekResim);
            TextView yemekIsim = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_yemekIsim);
            TextView yemekSure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_yemekSure);
            TextView yemekMalzemeler = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_malzemeler);
            TextView yemekTarif = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_tarif);

            yemekTarifi secilenYemek = yemekTarifleriList.get(position);

            yemekResim.setImageResource(secilenYemek.getResim());        //(line 67)!!!!!!!!!!!!
            yemekIsim.setText(secilenYemek.getIsim());
            yemekSure.setText(secilenYemek.getHazirlanisSuresi());
            yemekMalzemeler.setText(secilenYemek.getMalzemeler());
            yemekTarif.setText(secilenYemek.getTarif());

            setContentView(R.layout.yemek_tarifi);



        }
    });
```

Error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.erensayar_yemektarifi, PID: 13293
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference
>           at com.example.erensayar_yemektarifi.anaSayfa_yemekTarifleri$1.onItemClick(anaSayfa_yemekTarifleri.java:67)
>           at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1159)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3136)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4052)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Codes are uploaded to github : github.com/erensayar/android

Comment: Please post your item layout xml file.

Comment: I uploded to github : github.com/erensayar/android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. 
I forget open an activity class for my target layout. I was created layout but i didn't create an activity. 
And then, I should my data's i have to send other activity (my layout adapter) from listview onclick activity.

And we should use intent
Like this:

//This block allready had

```
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lw_yemekTarifleri);
    customAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(this, yemekTarifleriList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

//when we click on element in the listview (Sender)

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            setContentView(R.layout.yemek_tarifi_yemek_tarifleri);
            yemekTarifi secilenYemek = yemekTarifleriList.get(position);

            //Log.d("OnClick", "position = " + yemekTarifleriList.get(position));


            //Elemanları layouta bastırmak için bu verileri öbür activity'e yani istediğimiz layouta göndermeliyiz. O da intent.putextra ile oluyor.
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yemekTarifiAdapter.class);


            intent.putExtra("isim", secilenYemek.getIsim());
            intent.putExtra("malzemeler", secilenYemek.getMalzemeler());
            intent.putExtra("tarif", secilenYemek.getTarif());
            intent.putExtra("sure", secilenYemek.getHazirlanisSuresi());

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

//This block target loyout's class.(Adapter)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yemek_tarifi_yemek_tarifleri);

    ImageView yemekResim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iw_yemekResim);
    TextView yemekIsim = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_yemekIsim);
    TextView yemekSure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_yemekSure);
    TextView yemekMalzemeler = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_malzemeler);
    TextView yemekTarif = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_tarif);


    //Receiver 
    String isim = getIntent().getExtras().getString("isim");
    String malzemeler = getIntent().getExtras().getString("malzemeler");
    String tarif = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tarif");
    int sure = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("sure");



    yemekIsim.setText(isim);
    yemekSure.setText(String.valueOf(sure));
    yemekMalzemeler.setText(malzemeler);
    yemekTarif.setText(tarif);



}//OnCreate Sonu
```

Thanks to everyone who helped.

If want to see all new code : github/erensayar/android

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of secilenYemek object is it really initialized with a value or not.
My advice woulld be to setup a debug point just before line 67 i.e (line 66) and correctly check the value of secilenYemek object. As it is throwing null pointer exception because of it.

Comment: You are right. I did what u said. Variables are null. I got an idea, i will try and come back, thank you Arsalan.

Comment: My idea didn't work :) what should i do? How can i get variables and write layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  ImageView yemekResim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iw_yemekResim);
  TextView yemekIsim = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_yemekIsim);
  TextView yemekSure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_yemekSure);
  TextView yemekMalzemeler = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_malzemeler);
  TextView yemekTarif = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_tarif);

final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lw_yemekTarifleri);
customAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(this, yemekTarifleriList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);


listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Log.i("OnClick", "position = " + position);



        yemekTarifi secilenYemek = yemekTarifleriList.get(position);

        yemekResim.setImageResource(secilenYemek.getResim());        
        yemekIsim.setText(secilenYemek.getIsim());
        yemekSure.setText(secilenYemek.getHazirlanisSuresi());
        yemekMalzemeler.setText(secilenYemek.getMalzemeler());
        yemekTarif.setText(secilenYemek.getTarif());

        setContentView(R.layout.yemek_tarifi);



    }
});
```

Comment: I tried but it wasnt work and this code more reasonable, thank you.